# sort strings in perl according to date

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a set of strings:

```
$str1: 7-10-2013- X1
$str2: 19-04-2010-G2
$str3: 7-10-2013-X2
$str4: 7-12-2013-A
```

I want to sort the strings according to the date and the Alphabet in the end. SO, the above strings after sorting will be:

```
$str2: 19-04-2010-G2
$str1: 7-10-2013-X1
$str3: 7-10-2013-X2
$str4: 7-12-2013-A
```

My idea of doing this would be to do regex grouping and then sort according to each group. But I am looking for more efficient ideas to implement this in perl.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and the fact that dates in YYYYMMDD format sort lexicographically:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @strings = qw(7-10-2013-X1 19-04-2010-G2 7-10-2013-X2 7-12-2013-A);

print "$_\n" for map $_->[1],
                 sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
                 map {
                     my ($d, $m, $y, $str) = split /-/;
                     [sprintf('%d%02d%02d%s', $y, $m, $d, $str), $_]
                 }
                 @strings;
```